# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5

Tags: java, android

i am new in android development. i am working on an app where i am using navigation drawer, in which i have seven items.i am using an arraylist for them to show them on onCreate.

```
navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5,-1), true, "50+"));

     navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
```

but i am facing this problem.

Caused by:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
            at com.almuntazah.application.Homepage.onCreate(Homepage.java:75)
```

can anyone please tell me in simple words what should i do?? thank you so much.
actually i get error in last 2 lists. if i remove them, i can't get in my application.

Comment: you are accessing element out of bounds. Java arrays and lists are zero based, which means first element of an array is at index `0`, and the last is at position `array.length-1`

Answer (score 2):

You need to count from zero so your last field of an array with the length of 5 is 4

Example:

```
    String examplearray[]=new String [5];
    System.out.println(examplearray.length)
    >>>5//this is the length
    examplearray={"1","2","3","4","5"}//filling the array
    System.out.println(examplearray.length)
    >>>5//still the same length
    System.out.println(examplearray[4])
    >>>"5"//the content of the examplearray[4] field
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array navMenuTitles has 5 objects in it, from 0 to 4. **(Arrays in Java are zero-based)**

Here you try to access to 7 objects from 0 to 6. This error says that object 6 and 7 (index 5 and 6) can't be accessed and it is fair, because they do not exist.